# Which depiction of the world map, with focus on dry land vs ocean do you think is more accurate? Scotese's or deeptimemaps?

Tags: glaciology, isostasy

[image: This top image is Scotese's for 3.7 million years ago from https://www.academia.edu/11082185/Atlas_of_Neogene_Paleogeographic_Maps]

[image: The bottom image is for DeeptimeMaps who are affiliated with Petroleum, for 4 million years ago from https://deeptimemaps.com/global-paleogeography-and-tectonics-in-deep-time/]

Special attention paid particularly to the Arctic where the Hudson and Berent's sea are ocean in the above they are ocean, below they are land.

In other places, Scotese's seems more accurate to me but I can's shake the feeling that up North, Scotese might be ignoring the effect of Glacial depression.

For one, from this rate of isostatic rebound map,

[image: Rate of Isostatic rebound pale yellow, neutral, towards red, positive, towards blue, negative]

Its is rebounding as much as land areas that were covered by Ice Sheets which implies it was just as deeply covered by ice sheets which is kinda weird, especially with areas of Ice over the Sea in Antarctica today being covered negative while the rest of the land glaciers are positive.

This implies it was in a condition just as primed for having ice sheets as, say Scandinavia therefore, land.

But which do you think is more accurate, particularly in the arctic.

Comment: Are you sure they're not showing different time periods?